# Why is the discrete logarithm problem in $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$ easy?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have trouble understanding why the discrete logarithm problem in $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$ should be easy:

I tried it with the following example:

$$a \cdot b \equiv y \pmod {p}$$
If $a=11, b=2$ and $p=19$:
$$11 \cdot 2 \equiv 3 \pmod {19}$$

If someone now has $b, y$ and $p$ how can he calculate $a$ efficiently?

$$a \cdot 2 \equiv 3 \pmod{19}$$

Comment: modular division.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Hurkyl
If I look into this topic: (for instance on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work) I only find how I can calculate the remainder but not the integer which led to that remainder. Is it because I could have multiple answers leading to the same remainder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using extended Euclidean algorithm, find integers $m, n$ such that $$bm+pn = GCD(b,p) = 1$$

For instance, $$2\cdot(-9)+19\cdot1 = 1$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\begin{align*}
bm&\equiv1&&\pmod p\\
2\cdot(-9)&\equiv1&&\pmod{19}\\
2\cdot10&\equiv1&&\pmod{19}\\
\end{align*}$$

This $(m\bmod p)$ is usually called the multiplicative inverse of $b$, or $b^{-1}$. Multiply both sides of $a\cdot2 \equiv3$ by $b^{-1} = (m\bmod p)=10$,
$$\begin{align*}
abb^{-1}&\equiv yb^{-1}&&\pmod p\\
a\cdot1&\equiv yb^{-1}\\
a\cdot2\cdot10 &\equiv3\cdot10 &&\pmod{19}\\
a&\equiv30\equiv11
\end{align*}$$
As you can see, $b$ cannot be a multiple of $p$, unless $y = 0$.